# JBoss 7 Password Hashing

Tags: java, security, jboss

I have an application deployed on a JBoss 7 Server that uses Form Based Authentication. There was a nice example of how to use the JBoss baked in security utility to easily hash passwords, but I guess the encryption has been updated in 7, because I cannot find the JAR that has the Util class anywhere in the JBoss installation directory.

Can anyone point me to the equivalent of this for JBoss7?

```
import org.jboss.security.auth.spi.Util;

public class PasswordGenerator {

   private String generate(String password) {
      return Util.createPasswordHash("SHA-256", "BASE64", null, null,password);
   }
}
```

My project is a maven project, so ideally I would like to find the jar in the maven repository, and not have to include a local jar.

Comment: Hashing. There is no encryption here.

Answer (score 0):

The `org.jboss.security.auth.spi.Util` class is in the PicketBox module:

```
jboss-as-7.1.1.Final/modules/org/picketbox/main/picketbox-4.0.7.Final.jar
```

You can also use OpenSSL command line utility to generate the password hash:

```
echo -n password | openssl dgst -sha256 -binary | openssl base64
```